# How to access the array of object response in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a response from an API, and this is the response when I viewed it using `console.log(myArray)`.

I need to write the code in TypeScript Angular 6.

```
Output:Array(2)

 0:{ q1: 2
       q2:. 1
        __proto__: Object
     }
 1:{ q1: 2
       q2:. 1
      __proto__: Object
    }
 ___proto__: Array(0)
__proto__:object
```

Now I need to get the values of q1 and q2 in array. I tried but I am unable to do it.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you want it in HTML or inside component only

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

So, your Array has 2 elements in it.

**1**st is `{q1: 2, q2:..}`

the **2**nd is `{q1: 2, q2:..}` also.

It looks like this: `[{q1: 2, q2: ..}, {q1: 2, q2: ..}]`

So you need the values of q1 and q2 out of array?
Well, you have two copies of q1/q2 in your two separate objects. It's unclear whether they are the same.

If you just need the q1/q2 from the first object in your array, you can do the following:

```
let arr = [{q1: 2, q2: 3}, {q1: 2, q2: 3}]
arr[0].q1 // this is q1
arr[0].q2 // this is q2
```

If the q1/q2 values in each object are different, and you need all values of q1/q2, then you will need to loop through your array and get q1/q2 one by one. Like so:

```
let arr = [{q1: 2, q2: 3}, {q1: 2, q2: 3}]
arr.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.q1, obj.q2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
result = [];
getResult(myArray) {
  for(let i = 0;i < myArray.length;i++) {
    this.result.push(myArray[i]['q1']);
    this.result.push(myArray[i]['q2']);
   }
console.log(this.result);
return this.result;
}
```